# Will someone please explain this equation from the picture

Tags: limits, summation, exponential-function, factorial

I am trying to understand the following equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^m}{m!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}a^kb^{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+b)^n}{n!}$$

[Old  image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q2OE.jpg)

Its from the real & complex analysis book of Walter Rudin. It is a proof of the formula,
$e^ae^b = e^{a+b}$

But I don't know how we get the second and third expressions. How are the limits changed?

Comment: The third expression comes from the second using a binomial expansion in reverse.  To see how the second comes from the first, see what you get on each side with $k$, $m$ and $n$ running from $0$ to say $3$ and see how the terms match

Comment: the second step comes from putting $k+m=n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equality follows from the multiplication theorem for the product of absolutely convergent series. (see Rudin's Principles theorem 3.50; actually only one of the series needs to converge absolutely). This justifies the first equality, (in the expression below the second equality) and we get

$$Exp(a)Exp(b) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^m}{m!} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{k}\frac{a^pb^{k-p}}{p!(k-p)!}  
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{p=0}^{k}\binom{k}{p}a^pb^{k-p} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+b)^k}{k!} = Exp(a+b)$$
Besides the aforementioned theorem, only elementary manipulations and the binomial theorem were used.